# how to disable form validation from non-conditional formControls

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

my problem is about a form-control which has no validation conditions but after submit it shows the success mark which i don't need it

so is there a way to remove the validation from it?

```
<Form
   noValidate
   validated={validated}
   onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
>
<Form.Control as="textarea" rows="3" />
```

[image: aa]

Comment: try `validated={false}` to prevent it from showing the validation styles?

Comment: doesnt work! @Sagivb.g

Answer (score 0):

Delete type="submit" from the insert button. It makes the form call the onSubmit function and then it decides whether it is going to reload the page if form is filled or not. You don't need this props `noValidate
   validated={validated}
   onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}` as well.